# How to get the instance name (instance-id) of a JBoss EAP 7 instance serving the request

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss-eap-7

The JBoss EAP 7 server instance-id is configured on standalone.xml, like this:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.1" instance-id="node2">
```

I have and environment with load balancing and sticky session. So, the client receives the JSESSIONID cookies with something like this as value: "ckvLpSqtsN2EjA8WpFqml3UMU5ZIyH2YI29Ir-i.node2".

**The question is:** I'm on the MBean (with access to FacesContext). How can I get the instance-id of the server that is serving the request? In the above scenario, "node2".

What I already tried:

1. FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionId(true).

   - Doesn't work because it strips the instance-id from the value in JSESSIONID.
2. Reading the JSESSIONID value from the "Cookie" header (avaiable via HttpServletRequest).

   - Doesn't work when the user doesn't have a session yet (he has no JSESSIONID cookie).

I have considered avoiding the problem by setting the instance id in an environment variable and configuring standalone.xml to define instance-id="${my.instance.name}". The application, then, reads the environment variable to get the instance-id. This is portable accross AS, but is prone to configuration error. Ideally the application should get exactly what is on instance-id and I don't need the application to be portable.

This question is similar to "Getting instance name of a WebSphere app Server" ([Getting instance name of a WebSphere app Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10619021/2394617)), but for a JBoss EAP 7 server.

Comment: Try with `System.getProperty("jboss.node.name")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it is a bug or a feature, but setting instance-id as described in the question does not change jboss.node.name or jboss.server.name:

- jboss.node.name is set as the **host name**;
- jboss.server.name is set as the **host name**;
- Cookie JSESSIONID has the **instance-id** appended on the end.

**However**, adding a name="node123" attribute on `<server>` tag (the top level element on standalone.xml) and removing the instance-id attribute from undertow have the following effects:

- jboss.node.name is set as "node123";
- jboss.server.name is set as "node123";
- Cookie JSESSIONID has "node123" appended at the end.

This is not exactly the answer I was expecting, but I find it more acceptable than defining a custom property and making sure that property is on "instance-id".

Answer (score 0):

It might not be directly related to the question but after performing some tests in wildfly10 we concluded the following related to different properties that are unique between nodes:

- `-Djboss.node.name=clusternode1`
  Uniquely identify each node in the cluster. You can see it in the logs. If missing the value of `jboss.server.name` is used which is normally the hostname.
- `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.1" instance-id="node1"`
  This affects the return cookie generated by each node. It can be utilized by the load-balancer to maintain sticky-sessions without the requirement to keep track of cookies.
  e.g: if cookie is suffixed with `.node1` I will send it on backend-server1 / if cookie is suffixed with `.node2` I will send it on backend-server2
- `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transaction:3.0"> <core-environment node-identifier="node1"`
  The documentation says that *it should be something unique*. 
  This is used *in case more than one servers are running on the same host*. see this diagram: [operating-modes](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Operating+modes#Operatingmodes-ManagedDomain)
  If you leave the default value you will get a warning. The warning changed in wildfly11 to be more descriptive: https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/commit/732429b98fc08a01410058a707c73c1dd52c75b1