# com.ibm.websphere.runtime.servername.getDisplayName() is None

Tags: websphere

As suggested in the below linked question....
[Getting instance name of a WebSphere app Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619021/getting-instance-name-of-a-websphere-app-server/10635824?s=1|0.5655#10635824)

I am calling ServerName.getDisplayName() in an existing python file but i get None as the result.
Basically I want the above displayname to set as  "Generic JVM arguments" in websphere console. 
The pyton script runs fine through our ant target, and I can see the one of the jvm args set as None in websphere console.

Any ideas why I am getting None? The websphere console is showing server name as "server1", so I expect ServerName.getDisplayName() should return that.

===================================
Response to covener:

file1.py is called from an ant target. Please see attachment for the result.

file1.py
start---------------------------------------

```
import file2

file2.configSystemProperties()
file2.saveConfiguration()
```

end---------------------------------------

file2.py
start---------------------------------------

```
from com.ibm.websphere.runtime import *

import websphere
.....
def configSystemProperties():
    websphere.setGenericJvmArguments("-Dtangosol.coherence.override=coherence.xml -DlogsDirName=" + str(ServerName.getDisplayName()));
.....

def saveConfiguration() :
    websphere.save()
```

end---------------------------------------

websphere.py file
start---------------------------------------

```
....
AdminConfig      = AdminConfigClient.getInstance();
....
def setGenericJvmArguments(genericJvmArguments):
    print "JVM generic arguments " + str(genericJvmArguments);
    AdminConfig.modify(jvm, [
        ["genericJvmArguments", genericJvmArguments]
    ])

def save() :
    logMajor("Saving...")
    AdminConfig.save()
    logMajor("Save complete.")

....
```

end---------------------------------------

Result:
[screenshot of websphere console showing None](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLRXs.png)

Comment: What's your code or an example that illustrates the problem?

Comment: I added code/example to the question above. Please take a look.

Comment: Also added the link to the screenshot of the websphere console showing the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you can't call the static method Server.getDisplayName() if your code isn't running in an application server process.  This is not really a wsadmin / scripting library API

Instead, you need to lookup the server with the Admin APIs.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/txml_listrunapp.html

Comment: Server.getDisplayName() did return right name in runtime. I created my own appenders and in the appender i called above method and it worked.