# Getting WebSphere full server name using JNDI

Tags: java, websphere, jndi

At the top of the WebSphere log file, I see a couple of lines:

```
WebSphere Platform 8.5 blah blah running with process name abc\xyz\pqr and process id 1234
Full server name is abc\xyz\pqr-1234
```

I would like to get the value `pqr` shown in the above two lines using Java code in my application that runs on the WebSphere server. I found that I could get the values `abc` and `xyz` by doing JNDI lookup, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19159678) to another question:

```
(new InitialContext()).lookup("thisNode/cell/cellname").toString();    // returns "abc"
(new InitialContext()).lookup("thisNode/nodename").toString();     // returns "xyz"
```

However, JNDI lookup of "servername" does not return `pqr` or any of the values above, but something else entirely.

How can I get the value `pqr` (or the entire value `abc\xyz\pqr` or `abc\xyz\pqr-1234`, whichever is possible)? I would prefer to get the value by doing a JNDI lookup rather than by using a WebSphere class like com.ibm.websphere.runtime.ServerName as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10635824), but if that is not possible I can use any solution that works.

I realize there may be questions about why I need to get the value and perhaps even opinions that it may not be a good practice to get that value etc. However, I have a valid and unavoidable reason for doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a [document about how to capture a WebSphere namespace dump](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tnam_dump_utility.html), including example output, showing entries such as,

```
(top)/nodes/outpost/nodename 
(top)/nodes/outpost/servers/server1/servername
```

Have you tried a look up of the following?

```
thisNode/servers/thisServer/servername
```

Comment: JNDI lookup of `thisNode/servers/thisServer/servername` results in a NamingException. Ultimately I had to use the strategy described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10629627/14697249) to another question.

Answer (score 0):

Well this answer is not a *JNDI* solution, however it is a solution to this problem. WebSphere provides class **com.ibm.websphere.runtime.ServerName** which is used for exactly this scenario. It has bunch of utility methods like:

- getDisplayName()
- getServerId()
- getFullName()

So how to use this class in your project while still being able to deploy project on a non-websphere environments? By checking in runtime if you are running within WebSphere, and if you do, than invoking methods within *ServerName*.

In order to not pollute your project with unnecessary dependencies to was runtime create a new utility jar project and add dependencies:

- com.ibm.ws.runtime-xxxx.jar as provided dependency (part of was or was client)
- spring-core-xxxx.jar as runtime dependency

Rest of the solutions are in following two methods withing two classes. One which checks for presence of websphere and other which interacts with it:

```
import org.springframework.util.ClassUtils;

public class WasInfo {

    /** 
     * @return a map populated with relevant WebSphere names
     *         if running on WebSphere or empty one if not
     */
    public Map<String, String> about() {
        ClassLoader currentClassLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        boolean isWebsphere = ClassUtils.isPresent("com.ibm.websphere.runtime.ServerName", currentClassLoader);
        if (!isWebsphere ) {
            return new HashMap<>();
        }
        
        WebSphereConfig wc = new WebSphereConfig();
        return wc.resolveServerName();
    }       
}


import com.ibm.websphere.runtime.ServerName;

public class WebSphereConfig {      
    public Map<String, String> resolveServerName() {
        // expecting 'cell/node/server' pattern     
        String serverFullName = ServerName.getFullName();
        String serverName = ServerName.getDisplayName();        
        
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("serverFullName", serverFullName);
        map.put("serverName", serverName);      
        
        String[] segments = serverFullName.split("\\\\");
        if (segments.length == 3) {
            map.put("cellName", segments[0]);
            map.put("nodeName", segments[1]);
        }
    }   
}
```

I used Spring's ClassUtils to get rid of some boring code in this example. And for exercise one could invoke ServerName methods using reflections. That would remove a need for import ServerName statement and make code even more "simpler". But idea would remain the same.